# Dynamically load ajax content on fancybox from MySQL database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, fancybox

I have this code to display fancybox links. How it works now is:
I select 4 entries from MySQL database which are matching a category. And again for all categories on my page. I set a rel='x' for entries matching category 'x'. 
Idea of what i want to do is 'go deeper into category'. It means when finish viewing 4 items from rel='x' group, select from mysql database nextcoming entry to display but not display at the page where these 4 links are. Entries are ordered by id DESC.

```
<a  class="various fancybox.ajax" data-fancybox-type="ajax" rel="group" 
    href="view.php?&id=<?php echo $rw10['id']; ?>"></a>

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".various").fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 800,
        maxHeight   : 800,
        fitToView   : false,
        width       : '70%',
        height      : '100%',
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        'closeBtn' : false,
         openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        nextEffect  : 'none',
        prevEffect  : 'none',
        preload: true,
        padding     : 10,
        margin      : [20, 60, 20, 60] // Increase left/right margin
    });
```

Comment: not sure i really understand your problem

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is to get the coming (related) items from your database and store them in a *json* variable like :

```
var databaseResponse = [{
    href: "path/image05.jpg", // 4 are visible on page so
    type: "image",
    title: "Image #5",
    isDom: false
}, {
    href: "path/image06.jpg",
    type: "image",
    title: "Image #6",
    isDom: false
}, {
    href: "path/image07.jpg",
    type: "image",
    title: "Image #7",
    isDom: false
}]; // etc
```

Then `push` the items from that variable into the gallery within the `beforeLoad` callback like :

```
var done = false; // initialize switch
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        // loop : false, // optional
        beforeLoad: function () {
            // here get next items from database 
            // and store them in a json variable
            // e.g. "databaseResponse"
            if ((this.index == this.group.length - 1) && !done) {
                for (var i = 0; i < databaseResponse.length; i++) {
                    this.group.push(databaseResponse[i]);
                };
                done = true; // push items only once
            }
        },
        afterClose: function () {
            done = false; // reset switch
        }
    });
}); // ready
```

**Notice** that we are using a *switch* (the `done` variable) to *push* the items only once (we may need to reset the *switch* after closing fancybox though)

**<kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/49MsR/)</kbd>**

**NOTE** : the items will be added (pushed) only after we are seeing the last item in the DOM (the 4th in your case) so if you start browsing the gallery backwards, you won't see the new items but until the second loop.

You may want to  set `loop` to `false` though

Comment: Its almost what i need. But i have 2 more questions:
1. im new to javascript so i dont know where MySQL part is supposed to be. tell me if im right:
  1.1 Select ids from database `WHERE id NOT IN (1,2,3,4)`
  1.2 Loop selected ids with PHP inside of `var databaseResponse`
2. if content type is ajax i should specify it on `type` parameter?
3. how can i split items from `var databaseResponse` by different `rels` ? because i have more categories than just one
thank you