# jQuery fancybox first image is "..cannot be loaded content.." but images are loaded on next

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have a fancybox created (dynamically), and the first popup shows the "cannot be loaded content" but the fact is the images are all loaded on the next frames.

I can't figure out why it would show the error message first.

[`JSFIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/xiomai/9wLyc/3/)

Here is a jsfiddle with thumbnails to show the images are loaded.

I got the original code from this [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22826452/1935885).

WORKING CODE:

```
$(".v-gallery").on("click", function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var databaseResponse = (function () {
        var json = null;
        $.ajax({
            'async': false,
            'global': false,
            'url': 'ajaxJsonVGallery.php',
            'data': {'i': id},
            'type':'post',
            'dataType': "json",
            'success': function (data) {
                json = data;
            }
        });
        return json;
    })();

    $.fancybox(databaseResponse, {
        padding: 0,
        helpers: {
            title: {
                type: 'outside'
            },
            thumbs: {
                width: 50,
                height: 50
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});

....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scenario of this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22826452/1935885) where you got the code from, is different than yours because it shows how to add images dynamically to an **existing** gallery.

In your case, you don't have an existing gallery but you are creating it entirely from a database response (I assume)

Since you don't have a gallery, your link (the `href` attribute) is not pointing  to any image neither to a `div` with ID `gallery` so "the content cannot be loaded"

```
<a href="#gallery" id='00' class='v-gallery'>View Images</a>
```

If you want to launch your dynamically created gallery from the same link, then you should rather store the database response in a *variable* and then open fancybox programmatically after a `click` event on the selector `.v-gallery` like :

```
var databaseResponse = [{
    href: "http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2870/8985207189_01ea27882d_b.jpg",
    type: "image",
    title: "Image #3",
    isDom: false
}, {
    href: "http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3818/9036037912_83576fe5ab_b.jpg",
    type: "image",
    title: "Image #4",
    isDom: false
}, {
    href: "http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5471/9036958611_fa1bb7f827_b.jpg",
    type: "image",
    title: "Image #5",
    isDom: false
}];
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".v-gallery").on("click", function () {
        $.fancybox(databaseResponse, {
            helpers: {
                title: {
                    type: 'outside'
                },
                thumbs: {
                    width: 50,
                    height: 50
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
}); // ready
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pDAss/)**